# STS/Eclipse does not render the javadoc preview at Javadoc view

Tags: eclipse, javadoc, spring-tool-suite, sts, spring-tools-4

Having in 2 Laptops Linux Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 the following:

```
Spring Tool Suite 4 

Version: 4.17.2.RELEASE
Build Id: 202301310704
Revision: 4c43862ec9482cb5c289960e5514998e59d2f1fe

Eclipse Platform

Version: 4.26.0.v20221123-2302
Build id: I20221123-1800
```

And using `java - eclipse:temurin - jdk-17.0.6+10`

**Situation**

For both laptops happens the following: for any kind of java type: classes, interfaces, etc (written either by me or by other as Spring/Java) where exists available javadoc at any level (method, instance variable, etc) - when the `Javadoc` view is opened and the mouse's cursor is located in the javadoc content, the view always remains in blank. So nothing is rendered.

How to fix it? or Is need it an extra configuration in the IDE itself? - remember this situation is about to **render** the javadoc content in the the `Javadoc` view - it is **not** about javadoc generation - it is handled through Maven.

**Note** was uninstalled the `JAutodoc` plugin, but the situation remains. Was assumed that a kind of conflict happened.

**Update** This post was created on March and today at June with the same IDE version *suddenly and by first time* at startup appeared the following dialog window or popup (I didn't do an upgrade to the `DevStyle` plugin).

[image]

Was stopped and started again the IDE (no simply restarted) without the indicated command and the same popup did not appear again. Well, the IDE was stopped, executed the `export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1` command and now works the `Javadoc` view

Comment: My vague guess here is that this is related to problems with the internal browser component of SWT when running on this version of Linux/GTK. How does a plain Eclipse 4.28 installation behave?

Comment: Understood, let me test it soon as I can .... btw - what Eclipse presentation? the basic or JEE?

Comment: It shouldn't matter which Eclipse package, the Javadoc view comes from JDT, which is included everywhere.

Comment: I got the _eclipse-java-2023-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz_ file and the _JavaDoc_ view works fine.

Comment: Hmm, so `eclipse-java-2023-03-R-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz` works fine, but a `Spring Tools 4.18.0 release for Linux x86_64` does not? That is strange... That sounds like it is worth filing an issue at https://github.com/spring-projects/sts4/issues and discuss and investigate this deeper. Does anything related show up in the Error Log view?

Comment: Let me try do a clean installation with STS - without none plugin installation - I remember clearly that in the 2 laptops, the `AnyEdit Tool` plugin had issues in its installation process ... so perhaps there is a conflict - About the `View`  mentioned, let me check it, btw the `Problems` View has the same situation as `Javadoc` View too.

Comment: I confirmed with a STS clean installation the `Javadoc` view works fine. Therefore I am assuming it is conflict with some Plugin - the `Errors` and `Problem` views show warning and some errors, but nothing about related with this situation

Comment: @MartinLippert observe the "update" section ... interesting the situation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even when is not clear why after many months, since march to june, and with a huge amount of times that the IDE was started, the popup window appeared just once.

Therefore, prior to start the IDE by command, *as is accomplished since the beginning of its installation*, was executed the `export WEBKIT_DISABLE_COMPOSITING_MODE=1` command and now the `Javadoc` view works fine. Therefore was a conflict with `Wayland`